# How to connect two elements in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I need to connect two below mentioned webelement. In between I need to iterate the for loop

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='undefined/]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g[")
public WebElement test1;

@FindBy(xpath="]/path")
public WebElement test2;
```

For example -

```
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
//Need code for connect two element like test1 +i + test2.
}
```

Can you help me.

Comment: you mean you need to conjoin the visible text of the two webelements?

Comment: Yes I need to join

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Post a link to the page or the relevant HTML and explain in words (with examples) what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

To combine the text of the two elements, you can do something like this -

```
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
 System.out.println(test1.getText() +i + test2.getText());
}
```

**EDIT -** 
You are actually trying to create a dynamic xpath based on a loop. Note that you don't have to create two WebElements for that because they aren't really a WebElement since their xpaths is not complete in itself and hence will not be associated with any of the elements.

Now, it is not possible to do that with PageFactory to create dynamic elements like that. To implement that out of box, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366094/dynamic-using-in-findsby-with-selenium). Otherwise, you need to use conventional `driver.findElement()` Note how I have used `String` objects instead of `WebElement` -

```
String test1 = "//*[@id='undefined/]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g[";
String test2 = "]/path";

for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
driver.findElement(By.xpath((test1 + i + test2)))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply, but i need to connect webelement not text "

Comment: What do you mean by "connect webelement"? Like placing the two separate elements together side by side in the HTML?

Comment: Yes for example //*[@id='undefined/]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g[ - Test 1,   "]/path" - test2. Need connect these two welement.

Comment: What is the example? Why do you need a for loop for such a scenario? Please update the question with more details.

Comment: Orginal Xpath : //*[@id='undefined/]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g[1]/path. I separte 
 two the xpath as //*[@id='undefined/]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g[  and ]/path. Need to get the value from the forloop to iterate in g[1] tag

Comment: @SaravanakumarMarudhachalam refer my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to concatenate two strings and then produce xpaths during runtime. Will this help?

```
String xpath1 "//*[@id='undefined/]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/svg/g
for (int i=1; i<=10; i++){
String finalxpath = xpath1+"["+i+"]/path"

}
```