# Put a variable into find.By CSS but got error: "Attribute value must be a constant" for Selenium /Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to put a variable in a css selector but I get an error. I have 3 classes: Flight (where I have the locations with my selector and I'm getting the error, the code comes from here) and TestCase2 (where I use the localized element to test it). This is the code with the error

```js
    
    private String day;
    @FindBy(css = "button.datepicker-cal-date[data-day='"+ day +"']")
    private WebElement selectDay;
   
    public WebElement getSelectDay(String day){return selectDay;} 
    
    
    public void clickOnSelectDay(String day){
        System.out.println("Click on select day on the data picker");
        getSelectDay(day).click();

    }
```

I want to be able to click on a specific day, the day I'm going to put in the variable in class TC2.

Excuse me if it's something silly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366094/dynamic-using-in-findsby-with-selenium refer this link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I heard about `FindBy` and `FindBys` is they accept only String which cannot be modified i.e. a `final` String because the `final` keyword prevents future assignments to the variable. I am not sure but you can try in below mentioned way.

```
private final String dayCSS1="button.datepicker-cal-date[data-day='";
private final String dayCSS2="']";
private final String day;
@FindBy(css = dayCSS1 + day + dayCSS2)
private WebElement selectDay;
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. just add the value into private final String day = "5"

Comment: If all you are going to do is hardcode the day, then you can just use `@FindBy(css = "button.datepicker-cal-date[data-day='5']")` and save the 3 variables and concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

@FindBy does not allow you to do computation during runtime. As an Annotation, it runs before your script even starts.

### To use a variable in @FindBy

This won't help in this situation, but it may come in handy in the future. The key is using the `final` tag on your String. And therefore, it must be assigned something.

```
public final String cMonday= "button.datepicker-cal-date[data-day='Monday']";
@FindBy(css = cMonday)
public WebElement dayOfWeekMonday;
```

As a habit, I start the variable with the type of locator, 'c' for css and 'x' for xpath so I don't get them confused.

For your situation...

### Use a List<> and select the right one from an access method

First, create a List of all the buttons:

```
@FindBy(css = "button.datepicker-cal-date")
private List<WebElement> dayOfTheWeekButtons;
```

Then, select the right one via your method:

```
public void clickOnSelectDay(String day){
    for(WebElement dayName : dayOfTheWeekButtons) {
        if(day.equals(dayName.getAttribute("data-day")) {
            System.out.println("Click on select day on the data picker: " + day);
            dayName.click();
            break;
        }
    }
    fail();
}
```

The code may need some tweaking, but you should get the idea. From the list of names saved in the 'data-day' list, cycle through until you find the correct value, and then you can click on it.